# How to Fit an Image Exactly in a Div Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out how to fit an image exactly inside a box. I want my image to fit exactly in the box while still showing the border. Any help would be appreciated. As you can see the image is quite small, and I have messed around with the code for hours.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeIn(2000);
   $("#titlep").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#titlep {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav {
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

#firstimage > img {
  width: 200px;
  height : auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Global HypeBeast</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="titlep">
    <p>
      Welcome to Global HypeBeast, the best website for checking out street fashion from around the world. 
    </p>
    </div>
       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BRANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FASHION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="firstimage">
      <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a background image and stretch it?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%; height: 100%` to the image? It goes to full content

Comment: I'll be the first to recommend [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images). If you can't do that, then maybe try using percentages rather than fixed px measurements. They conform to the parent element. I don't recommend removing the img tag for semantic and searchability reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a percentage width and height of `100%` to your img tag like this:

```
#firstimage > img {
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

[If however, you want to maintain image aspect ratio, then leave height as `auto` but you will get a gap below the image if the aspect ratio of the box and the image differs]

Check snippet below to see the image with the above code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeIn(2000);
   $("#titlep").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#titlep {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav {
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

#firstimage > img {
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Global HypeBeast</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="titlep">
    <p>
      Welcome to Global HypeBeast, the best website for checking out street fashion from around the world. 
    </p>
    </div>
       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BRANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FASHION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="firstimage">
      <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the image as the background of `#firstimage`, and remove the img tag. Set the image size using [`background-size: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

```
#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url(http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

**Note**: the image will be blurred because it's resized up. In addition the image will be cropped, since the height / width ration is kept, and parts of it will resized outside the box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#firstheader").fadeIn(2000);
  $("#titlep").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
#titlep {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url(http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Global HypeBeast</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="firstheader">
    <h1>
    Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="titlep">
    <p>
      Welcome to Global HypeBeast, the best website for checking out street fashion from around the world.
    </p>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">BRANDS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">FASHION</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="firstimage"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```
object-fit:contain
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeIn(2000);
   $("#titlep").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#titlep {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav {
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

#firstimage > img {
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Global HypeBeast</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="titlep">
    <p>
      Welcome to Global HypeBeast, the best website for checking out street fashion from around the world. 
    </p>
    </div>
       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BRANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FASHION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="firstimage">
      <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`object-fit:cover` + `overflow`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeIn(2000);
   $("#titlep").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#titlep {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav {
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#firstimage > img {
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Global HypeBeast</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="titlep">
    <p>
      Welcome to Global HypeBeast, the best website for checking out street fashion from around the world. 
    </p>
    </div>
       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BRANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FASHION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="firstimage">
      <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also just specify `min-height` and `min-width` + `overflow` which is very similar to `object-fit:cover` + `overflow` but understood by old browsers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#firstheader").fadeIn(2000);
   $("#titlep").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
#firstheader {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#titlep {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav {
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstimage {
  width: 550px;
  height: 368px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#firstimage > img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Global HypeBeast</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="firstheader">
  <h1>
    Street Fashion WORLDWIDE
  </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="titlep">
    <p>
      Welcome to Global HypeBeast, the best website for checking out street fashion from around the world. 
    </p>
    </div>
       <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BRANDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FASHION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="firstimage">
      <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice these days is to use Bootstrap framework and also SVG for maintaining resolution. However, you can stretch the image to fit by adding style property to the  tag:

```
<img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
```